# How to use third party dependencies in a custom ansible module?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to use any third party dependencies in a custom Ansible module?

I looked in following page, but couldn't find any information regarding this.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html

I am using a custom ansible module in the `library` directory of one of my roles, and I need to use `PyYAML` in this custom module. I am not sure how this dependency would be resolved in a remote machine when this role is executed in a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post might help you:
[Pip dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536334/correct-way-to-setup-the-environment-when-developing-custom-ansible-modules-that)

And maybe also this can point you in the correct direction.
On the first URL Vladimir Botka points:

> To comment on your "expectation that there is some way to tell ansible to install the 3rd party libraries on the remote machine as part of its setup". Ansible shouldn't willy-nilly install 3rd party libraries on the remote. A recommended way to install it on the remote machine is Packaging modules. – Vladimir Botka Jun 11 '19 at 5:55